# C# if/then directives for debug vs release

Tags: c#, debugging, release, compiler-directives

In Solution properties, I have Configuration set to "release" for my one and only project.

At the beginning of the main routine, I have this code, and it is showing "Mode=Debug". 
I also have these two lines at the very top:

```
#define DEBUG 
#define RELEASE
```

Am I testing the right variable?

```
#if (DEBUG)
            Console.WriteLine("Mode=Debug"); 
#elif (RELEASE)
            Console.WriteLine("Mode=Release"); 
#endif
```

My goal is to set different defaults for variables based on debug vs release mode.

Comment: You are defining BOTH debug and release.

Answer (score 907, accepted):

`DEBUG`/`_DEBUG` should be defined in VS already.

Remove the `#define DEBUG` in your code. Set preprocessors in the build configuration for that specific build.

The reason it prints "Mode=Debug" is because of your `#define` and then skips the `elif`.

The right way to check is:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Mode=Debug"); 
#else
    Console.WriteLine("Mode=Release"); 
#endif
```

Don't check for `RELEASE`.

Comment: I wanted to add that if one only wanted to check for RELEASE then one can do this: #if !DEBUG

Comment: Why `#if` and not `#ifdef`?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Remember we are talking about C# here, not C. `#ifdef` is specific to the preprocessor of C/C++, C# mandates the use of `#if`.

Comment: Awesome.  And ReSharper is smart enough to "gray out" the line of code that will not be executed.

Comment: @Jess, I believe this is Visual Studio doing the greying out, not ReSharper

Comment: How does one "Set preprocessors"?

Answer (score 367):

By default, Visual Studio defines `DEBUG` if project is compiled in Debug mode and doesn't define it if it's in Release mode. RELEASE is not defined in Release mode by default. Use something like this:

```
#if DEBUG
  // debug stuff goes here
#else
  // release stuff goes here
#endif
```

If you want to do something only in release mode:

```
#if !DEBUG
  // release...
#endif
```

Also, it's worth pointing out that you can use `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute on methods that return `void` to have them only executed if a certain symbol is defined. The compiler would remove all calls to those methods if the symbol is not defined:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void PrintLog() {
    Console.WriteLine("Debug info");
}

void Test() {
    PrintLog();
}
```

Answer (score 292):

I prefer checking it like this over looking for `#define` directives:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
   //...
}
else
{
   //...
}
```

With the caveat that of course you could compile and deploy something in debug mode but still not have the debugger attached.

Comment: Thank you! I don't yet even know what "#defines" are so this is a great solution!

Comment: And im my case, this does exactly what I want.  I actually want to know if I have a debugger attached, because I know I have some code I do not want executed if I have a debugger attached.  This is awesome!

Comment: If personally like using `#IF DEBUG` in situation of debugging code that shouldn't last. For production code I agree with using the above.

Comment: The draw back to doing this instead of using `#DEBUG` is that this if statement is in your code and always checked where as the `#DEBUG` answer removes the code that isn't applicable at compile time so you don't have a run-time check and your .exe (or whatever you compile to) is smaller.

Comment: For situations when you do want the debugger throws exception to be able to identify problem and correct it rapidly (one of the pros of going with .NET) ; #if DEBUG is more suitable

Comment: This might answer the intended question but it does not answer the stated question.

Comment: @user34660.  The answer to the stated question is "no", which doesn't really help anyone.

Comment: @Dan surely the difference is negligible. I suppose it is a good thing to keep in mind, but will only really matter if your code's performance is highly important or sensitive.

Comment: @Nacht-ReinstateMonica it's highly dependent on your program. If it's just one little small app or something that your managing yourself it's probably fine. But if your code base is big or there's a lot of people in it little inefficiencies like this really start to add up.

Comment: This answer is SUPERB for my problem; where I'm within my test framework and always in DEBUG mode but I don't always have my debugger attached.. perfectly solving my problem

Comment: This is complements #DEBUG perfectly: I can divide my logs between production, testing and logs from debug on the local machine.

Comment: Agree with @ornic above, why not use both `#if DEBUG` in combination with this to only output if a Debugger is attached -- especially if you are just outputting debug info via `Debug.WriteLine()`. So only if compiled in DEBUG mode, we then check to ensure a Debugger is attached via `if(Debugger.IsAttached)` before we write out additional debugging log info to the console, etc.

Answer (score 67):

I'm not a huge fan of the #if stuff, especially if you spread it all around your code base as it will give you problems where Debug builds pass but Release builds fail if you're not careful.

So here's what I have come up with (inspired by [#ifdef in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975355/ifdef-in-c-sharp/975370#975370)):

```
public interface IDebuggingService
{
    bool RunningInDebugMode();
}

public class DebuggingService : IDebuggingService
{
    private bool debugging;

    public bool RunningInDebugMode()
    {
        //#if DEBUG
        //return true;
        //#else
        //return false;
        //#endif
        WellAreWe();
        return debugging;
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    private void WellAreWe()
    {
        debugging = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey now, that's pretty creative.  I like your use of the attribute to set the property.

Comment: This has the advantage of not getting hit by refactoring bugs in Resharper that can mess up your code based on the current conditional setup.

Comment: I like this but i am wondering why not create a singleton implementation for this instead of a service. It's system specific and it stops you having to worry about injecting it everywhere. (can you envisage a scenario where the implementation of this functionality would be any different?

Comment: I actually have a singleton and service implementation in one class that I'm using now so you get to have the choice of which way to use it... Of course the service implementation has the benefit of being easier to "stub" out so that you can test both code paths...

Comment: I am wondering why `DebuggingService` is not a static class and why you need an interface?  Is this something to do with using this with an IoC container?

Comment: Yes. @Ben I like to avoid static if at all possible as it makes alternate code paths in a C# application harder to test... An IoC/DI container (e.g. Autofac) makes avoiding static easy as you can have static-like behaviour without using a static class (using single instance registration). See here for more info: https://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html

Comment: Awesomesauce! This needs more votes. I never even knew this attribute existed. 20 years writing C# and I'm still learning! :D

Answer (score 34):

```
bool isDebug = false;
Debug.Assert(isDebug = true); // '=', not '=='
```

The method [`Debug.Assert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has conditional attribute `DEBUG`. If it is not defined, the call **and the assignment** `isDebug = true` are [eliminated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> If the symbol is defined, the call is included; otherwise, the call (including evaluation of the parameters of the call) is omitted.

If `DEBUG` is defined, `isDebug` is set to `true` (and passed to `Debug.Assert` , which does nothing in that case).

Comment: This is also a pretty creative solution. :)

Comment: Nice.  For an iteration variable that needs to change between Debug and Release...
    `var iterations = 10;
     Debug.Assert((iterations = Int32.MaxValue) > 0);`

Answer (score 22):

If you are trying to use the variable defined for the build type you should remove the two lines ...

```
#define DEBUG  
#define RELEASE
```

... these will cause the *#if (DEBUG)* to always be true.

Also there isn't a default Conditional compilation symbol for *RELEASE*.  If you want to define one go to the project properties, click on the *Build* tab and then add RELEASE to the *Conditional compilation symbols* text box under the *General* heading.

The other option would be to do this...

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("Release");
#endif
```

Answer (score 15):

Be sure to define the DEBUG constant in the Project Build Properties. This will enable the `#if DEBUG`.  I don't see a pre-defined RELEASE constant, so that could imply that anything Not in a DEBUG block is RELEASE mode.

[image: Define DEBUG constant in Project Build Properties]

Answer (score 9):

NameSpace

```
using System.Resources;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Method

```
   private static bool IsDebug()
    {
        object[] customAttributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggableAttribute), false);
        if ((customAttributes != null) && (customAttributes.Length == 1))
        {
            DebuggableAttribute attribute = customAttributes[0] as DebuggableAttribute;
            return (attribute.IsJITOptimizerDisabled && attribute.IsJITTrackingEnabled);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Remove your defines at the top

```
#if DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine("Mode=Debug"); 
#else
        Console.WriteLine("Mode=Release"); 
#endif
```

Answer (score 8):

Slightly modified (bastardized?) version of the answer by Tod Thomson as a static function rather than a separate class (I wanted to be able to call it in a WebForm viewbinding from a viewutils class I already had included).

```
public static bool isDebugging() {
    bool debugging = false;

    WellAreWe(ref debugging);

    return debugging;
}

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
private static void WellAreWe(ref bool debugging)
{
    debugging = true;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It is worth noting here that one of the most significant differences between conditionally executing code based on `#if DEBUG` versus `if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)` is that the compiler directive **changes the code that is compiled**.  That is, if you have two different statements in an `#if DEBUG/#else/#endif` conditional block, only **one** of them will appear in the compiled code.  This is an important distinction because it allows you do do things such as conditionally compile method definitions to be `public void mymethod()` versus `internal void mymethod()` depending on build type so that you can, for example, run unit tests on debug builds that will not break access control on production builds, or conditionally compile helper functions in debug builds that will not appear in the final code if they would violate security in some way should they escape into the wild.  The `IsAttached` property, on the other hand, does not affect the compiled code.  Both sets of code are in all of the builds - the `IsAttached` condition will only affect what is **executed**.  This by itself can present a security issue.

Answer (score 5):

A tip that may save you a lot of time - don't forget that even if you choose `debug` under the build configuration (on vs2012/13 menu it's under BUILD => CONFIGURATION MANAGER) - that's not enough.

You need to pay attention to the PUBLISH `Configuration`, as such:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got to thinking about a better way. It dawned on me that #if blocks are effectively comments in other configurations (assuming `DEBUG` or `RELEASE`; but true with any symbol)

```
public class Mytest
    {
        public DateTime DateAndTimeOfTransaction;
    }

    public void ProcessCommand(Mytest Command)
        {
            CheckMyCommandPreconditions(Command);
            // do more stuff with Command...
        }

        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        private static void CheckMyCommandPreconditions(Mytest Command)
        {
            if (Command.DateAndTimeOfTransaction > DateTime.Now)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("DateTime expected to be in the past");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the definitions and check if the conditional is on debug mode. You do not need to check if the directive is on release mode.

Something like this:

```
#if DEBUG
     Console.WriteLine("Mode=Debug"); 
#else
    Console.WriteLine("Mode=Release"); 
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the purpose of these COMPILER directives are to tell the compiler NOT to include code, debug code,beta code, or perhaps code that is needed by all of your end users, except say those the advertising department, i.e. #Define AdDept you want to be able include or remove them based on your needs. Without having to change your source code if for example a non AdDept merges into the AdDept. Then all that needs to be done is to include the #AdDept directive in the compiler options properties page of an existing version of the program and do a compile and wa la! the merged program's code springs alive!.

You might also want to use a declarative for a new process that is not ready for prime time or that can not be active in the code until it's time to release it.

Anyhow, that's the way I do it.