# In Visual Studio how to add special cases for debug and release versions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# if/then directives for debug vs release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104099/c-sharp-if-then-directives-for-debug-vs-release)

I am working on a C# project and I like to know how to add special cases while I am running the program in the debugger in the Debug Mode I have access to certain resources that I would not normally have in the release version.

Here is what keeps happening, I have admin tools built into the program, that are just for debugging, like a button that says test and put what ever code I want to into it.  What keeps happening I forget to hide that button and I release it to the clients.  I would love to have that test button there only while it's running in the debug mode but not any other time.

This turns on my admin tools

```
rpg_Admin.Visible = true;
```

This turns off my admin tools

```
rpg_Admin.Visible = false;
```

Is there  a simple way to do this?

```
if Debug Mode
    rpg_Admin.Visible = true
```

or maybe while it's running in visual studio it's

```
rpg_Admin.Visible = true
```

but when it's running on it's own

```
rpg_Admin.Visible = false
```

I am running on Visual Studio 2010

Thanks.

Comment: Dear mods: In my opinion, that isn't the same question. Its similar, but not an exact dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using your example, add some #if / #else / #endif directives like so:

```
#if DEBUG
    rpg_Admin.Visible = true;
#else
    rpg_Admin.Visible = false;
#endif
```

You could also apply `System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute` attributes to any code that's only used in the debug version. That will completely remove any unnecessary code from the release build. Example:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void MyDebugOnlyMethod()
    {
    }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for exactly!  I did not know it was that easy.

Comment: Well, nothing's easy until you know how to do it! That's why Stack Overflow is so awesome.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the debug code in #ifdef DEBUG/#endif:

```
#ifdef DEBUG

// debug only code here

#endif
```

Comment: hum,  for some reason #ifdef is not well liked, it gives me tons of errors.  Is there a special place for this, I am calling right after InitializeComponent(); in my form.

Comment: paste your code. you should be able to use ifdef anywhere...