# Debugging Feature Activation in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a simple feature using the feature receiver class in sharepoint 2010+ VS 2010.
But i am not able to debug the activate and deactivate method .
These are the following steps which I am following:

1. Add a receiver class to feature.
2. Update the active deployment configuration to :No Activation
3. Build the solution in debug mode.
4. Drag an drop the assembly from BIN to GAC folder.
5. Deploy the solution.
6. IISReset
7. Debugger>>Attach to process >>w3wp
   8.Activate the feature

Solution goes in debug mode but debugger did not stop at debugging point even then feature successfully triggered.
Please help..

Comment: You should be able to debug without manually copying assemblies: F5 should be enough if you've set the SharePoint Site Url in your project options. Is this a farm solution? The default is Sandbox and its code doesn't run in w3wp but SPUCWorkerProcess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling with the above remember you can always write to the event log.

Normally you are debugging because you are wary of a specific area of code. Sometimes I put these in to my code so I can track what the values are through the code and write to the application log an information event.

[C# if/then directives for debug vs release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104099/c-sharp-if-then-directives-for-debug-vs-release)

When you switch the code in to release the code in the above will be skipped over and irrelevant.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the feature template.xml file the feature receiver's class name and assembly are well specified, this how the receiver code kicks in
here is an example of the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
         Scope="Web"
         Id="guid"
         ReceiverAssembly="FullAssemblyName"
         ReceiverClass="FullClassName">
</Feature>
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an tiny, but important step. Especially if you are the only user of the SharePoint farm you are deploying to.

7. Reload a SharePoint page.

The reason for that is after IIS reset, you've killed SharePoint IIS process. You'd need it to be loaded again in order to properly attach Visual Studio to it.