# How to exclude methods when to deploy on IIS?

Tags: c#, wcf, deployment

I'm writing a WCF application exposing two methods.

What I need is to exclude a method when to deploy on IIS because the method is only used when to investigate a service for tests.

Instead of doing it by hands I want to achieve it automatically.

How can it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this might be of use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx ?

Also see also this for when #DEBUG is defined: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2104121/2462779 .

Comment: Thanks, the content in the second link is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this on the method for debug

```
 #if DEBUG
    [OperationContract]
 #endif
```

Then you have to compile in release mode.

Comment: Thanks for sharing one of possible ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Use two service interface: one with the method and one without it. Then expose the appropriate one to your clients.

Comment: I think your idea is also helpful. Thanks.