# Where predicates does not releases memory

Tags: c#, memory, datagrid

If I include outside reference inside `where predicate` then memory does not get releases.

Let's say I have a `List<object>` then if I write a `where predicate` like this :

```
    List<object> myList = new List<object>();
    ...
    myList.add(object);
    ...

    Expression<Func<object,bool>> predicate = p => myList.Contains(p);
```

Even If I make `myList = null` or `predicate = null`, it is not releasing memory.

I have `List<object> itemsource` binded to `DataGrid`. I also make it's ItemSource null, disposing DataGrid, DataGrid null. . I also have analyzed this issue with ANTS Memory Profiler 7.4. It also shows me that because of `wherepredicate` it is holding reference.

If I change my `wherepredicate` like this in `dispose()`, then memory is getting released.

```
    Expression<Func<object,bool>> predicate = p => p.id == 0;
```

that means removing reference in `WherePredicate`.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I suspect it *may* be a problem with the profiler you're using, or you may be misunderstanding it.

Comment: (There's not a lot of point in putting a bounty on a question if you're not going to respond to requests for clarification...)

Comment: Hey john... I have expalianed how I used in my project... I have analyzed this issue with Ants memory profiler.. But it shows me anonymous types...

Comment: You haven't provided a short but complete program allowing anyone else to reproduce this though, have you? (And the code you've shown isn't even valid C#, as you appear to be trying to use `object` as an identifier.)

Comment: I haven't provided a code... But the fact ... Just to let you know the cause of issue... Any ways I'm on mobile... I can not create a sample on mobile..

Comment: So wait until you're not on a mobile device, and then produce a short but complete program we can use to try to reproduce the issue. (I asked about that 4 days ago - I doubt that you've been stuck on a mobile device all that time...)

Comment: Leave it... I found a solution to solve this issue... I changed predicate on dispose()... Now memory is getting released... Thanks for showing interest

Comment: Well, that's not going to help anyone else. That means we're left with a post that can't be deleted because there's an upvoted answer, but not enough information to help any later visitors. Please think about Stack Overflow not just as a "help me" resource but as a repository of information for posterity.

Comment: Hey john I have also given a solution with the question...

Comment: Solutions shouldn't be in questions - they should be in *answers* - but as you haven't described the problem clearly enough, it's hard to know why your "solution" helps. I strongly suspect there are actually much better solutions, which we'd be able to suggest if we could reproduce the issue to start with...

Comment: You aren't asking a question.  Yes, an expression that uses an object is holding onto a reference to that object, and will keep it alive for as long as the expression is alive.  That's not a question.  If you want the object(s) referenced by an object to be able to be cleaned up, then the object(s) referencing them *also* need to be eligible for collection.

Comment: Servy When I use external reference into where predicate it creates anonymous object's and actually these objects holding it So, How I can clean them??

Comment: @Servy No... I've checked... Even `Expression<>` cause closure around a local variable, so they don't keep a reference to it directly, but to a hidden object. Modified my answer.

Comment: @AmolBavannavar The same way you do for any other object; it will be eligible for collection as soon as it's no longer possible for any executable code to access it through a managed reference.  in most situations this means ensuring that the scope of the variable(s) holding onto the object are such that they will go out of scope as soon as you no longer need them.  You say that you're setting it to another object instance, but you generally shouldn't be doing that; it's a sign that the scope of the variable is larger than it really should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mmmh... interesting... even `Expression<>` cause closure... I didn't know...

**the end result: predicate doesn't have a reference to myList**

I'll explain:

```
private static bool IsDebug()
{
    // Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104099/c-sharp-if-then-directives-for-debug-vs-release
    object[] customAttributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggableAttribute), false);

    if ((customAttributes != null) && (customAttributes.Length == 1))
    {
        DebuggableAttribute attribute = customAttributes[0] as DebuggableAttribute;
        return (attribute.IsJITOptimizerDisabled && attribute.IsJITTrackingEnabled);
    }

    return false;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Check x86 or x64
    Console.WriteLine(IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "x86" : "x64");

    // Check Debug/Release
    Console.WriteLine(IsDebug() ? "Debug, USELESS BENCHMARK" : "Release");

    // Check if debugger is attached
    Console.WriteLine(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ? "Debugger attached, USELESS BENCHMARK!" : "Debugger not attached");

    Console.WriteLine();

    {
        long memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        // A big array, big enough that we can see its allocation in
        // memory
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000000];

        Console.WriteLine("Just allocated the array: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // A List<>, containing a reference to the buffer
        List<object> myList = new List<object>();
        myList.Add(buffer);

        Console.WriteLine("Added to the List<>: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // We want to be sure that buffer is referenced at least up to
        // this point
        GC.KeepAlive(buffer);

        // But clearly setting buffer = null is useless, because the
        // List<> has anothe reference
        buffer = null;
        Console.WriteLine("buffer = null: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // If I Clear() the List<>, the last reference to the buffer
        // is removed, and now the buffer can be freed
        myList.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("myList.Clear(): {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        GC.KeepAlive(myList);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    GC.Collect();

    {
        long memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        // A big array, big enough that we can see its allocation in
        // memory
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000000];

        Console.WriteLine("Just allocated the array: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // A List<>, containing a reference to the buffer
        List<object> myList = new List<object>();
        myList.Add(buffer);

        Console.WriteLine("Added to the List<>: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // We want to be sure that buffer is referenced at least up to
        // this point
        GC.KeepAlive(buffer);

        // But clearly setting buffer = null is useless, because the
        // List<> has another reference
        buffer = null;
        Console.WriteLine("buffer = null: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // We want to be sure that the List<> is referenced at least
        // up to this point
        GC.KeepAlive(myList);

        // If I set to null myList, the last reference to myList
        // and to buffer are removed
        myList = null;
        Console.WriteLine("myList = null: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    GC.Collect();

    {
        long memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        // A big array, big enough that we can see its allocation in
        // memory
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000000];

        Console.WriteLine("Just allocated the array: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // A List<>, containing a reference to the buffer
        List<object> myList = new List<object>();
        myList.Add(buffer);

        Console.WriteLine("Added to the List<>: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // A predicate, containing a reference to myList
        Expression<Func<object, bool>> predicate1 = p => myList.Contains(p);
        Console.WriteLine("Created a predicate p => myList.Contains(p): {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // A second predicate, **not** containing a reference to
        // myList
        Expression<Func<object, bool>> predicate2 = p => p.GetHashCode() == 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Created a predicate p => p.GetHashCode() == 0: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // We want to be sure that buffer is referenced at least up to
        // this point
        GC.KeepAlive(buffer);

        // But clearly setting buffer = null is useless, because the
        // List<> has another reference
        buffer = null;
        Console.WriteLine("buffer = null: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // We want to be sure that the List<> is referenced at least
        // up to this point
        GC.KeepAlive(myList);

        // If I set to null myList, an interesting thing happens: the
        // memory is freed, even if the predicate1 is still alive!
        myList = null;
        Console.WriteLine("myList = null: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - memory);

        // We want to be sure that the predicates are referenced at 
        // least up to this point
        GC.KeepAlive(predicate1);
        GC.KeepAlive(predicate2);

        try
        {
            // We compile the predicate1
            Func<object, bool> fn = predicate1.Compile();
            // And execute it!
            fn(5);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("predicate1 is 'pointing' to a null myList");
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample test in three parts: the basic point is that a big `byte[]` array is allocated, and through checking how much memory is allocated we check if the array is still allocated in some way. **it is very important that this code is executed in Release mode without the debugger (CTRL+F5). If you don't do it, you'll get a warning when the program starts**

The first two "parts" are only to show that a `List<>` does keep "alive" the items it references (so the `byte[]` in this case), and freeing the `List<>` or `.Clear()`ing it lets the GC collect the `byte[]`.

The third part is more interesting: there are both a `List<>` and an `Expression<>`... Both seems to keep a reference to the `byte[]`, but this is an illusion. The `Expression<>` as written causes the compiler to generate a "closure" around the `myList<>` variable. Using ILSpy it is quite easy to see:

```
Program.<>c__DisplayClassb <>c__DisplayClassb = new Program.<>c__DisplayClassb();
<>c__DisplayClassb.myList = new List<object>();
<>c__DisplayClassb.myList.Add(buffer3);

ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p");
Expression<Func<object, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(Expression.Call(Expression.Field(Expression.Constant(<>c__DisplayClassb), fieldof(Program.<>c__DisplayClassb.myList)), methodof(List<object>.Contains(!0)), new Expression[]
{
    parameterExpression
}), new ParameterExpression[]
{
    parameterExpression
});
```

(if you don't have ILSpy, you can take a look at the code generated by the online compiler [TryRoslyn](http://goo.gl/We8xcm) for a simpler sample)

An hidden class `<>c__DisplayClassb` is generated by the compiler, with a field `myList`. So instead of having a "local" variable `myList`, the method has as a local variable `<>c__DisplayClassb` that has a field `myList`. The `predicate1` doesn't directly keep a reference to `myList`, but has a reference to the variable `<>c__DisplayClassb` (see the `Expression.Constant(<>c__DisplayClassb)`?), so when

```
<>c__DisplayClassb.myList = null;
```

the `predicate1` does still has a reference to `<>c__DisplayClassb`, but the `<>c__DisplayClassb.myList` is `null`, so there are no more references to `myList`.

Comment: @AmolBavannavar You could have multiple references to the predicate, to the list (you said you have a `DataGrid`), to the items and so on, and probably the code you are showing isn't the code you are running.

Comment: @AmolBavannavar Written a bigger sample.

Comment: @xanatos Yes that's I wanted to know... Thank you very much... This mean's a canonical answer...

Comment: Yes..  by clearing the list, It releases the memory... Your previous answer was absolutely right.. But just wanted to know why this happen's?.. Any ways.. Thanks a lott...