# Read data from app.config and use it across multiple classes in c#

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

Hi I am reading the values from app.config. I have different sections as below.

```
<TEST>
    <add key="key" value="value1" />
  </TEST>

  <DEV>
  <add key="key" value="value1" />
  </DEV>
```

I am accessing these values in my class files as below.

```
protected static NameValueCollection keyvalue = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("DEV") as NameValueCollection;
```

If I want to read values from 5 different classes then I have to write above code in all 5 classes and If I want to change **DEV** to **TEST** then I need to change in 5 places. Is there any way I can simplify this steps? Or Is there any best practices I can follow up? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

make a public static string containing the value you want.

Then just refer to that instead of directly inserting the value.

And whenever you want to change it, you just have to change the value of the static in that one place.

```
public static string Section = "DEV";
```

and then you can just insert this, so you only have to change the value of Section when you want to switch.

```
protected static NameValueCollection keyvalue = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(Section) as NameValueCollection;
```

Comment: any file as long as it's in the same assembly.
more info on the link added :)

Comment: @Niranjan if it worked, please mark as answer, if not, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Better to keep the string "DEV" in the app.config and then call the string as you are doing for the key and value. This helps in not building the console when you change the string.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would suggest following this link which tells how to manage debug and release mode in C#.[C# Debug & Release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104099/c-sharp-if-then-directives-for-debug-vs-release)