# How to run some code based on release or debug build mode?

Tags: c#, conditional-compilation, release-mode, debug-mode, conditional-execution

I have a variable(i.e `bool releaseMode = false;`)
I want the value of the variable to be set based on whether we are in release mode(`releaseMode = true;`) else debug mode(`releaseMode = false;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, you can use that:

```
/// <summary>
/// Indicate if the executable has been generated in debug mode.
/// </summary>
static public bool IsDebugExecutable
{
  get
  {
    bool isDebug = false;
    CheckDebugExecutable(ref isDebug);
    return isDebug;
  }
}

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
static private void CheckDebugExecutable(ref bool isDebug)
  => isDebug = true;
```

Of course you can swap name to:

```
IsReleaseExecutable

return !isDebug;
```

This approach implies that all code is compiled. Thus any code can be executed depending on this flag as well as any other behavior parameter concerning the user or the program, such as for example the activation or the deactivation of a debugging and tracing engine. For example:

```
if ( IsDebugExecutable || UserWantDebug )  DoThat();
```

Else a preprocessor directive like this:

[C# if/then directives for debug vs release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104099/c-sharp-if-then-directives-for-debug-vs-release)

[#if DEBUG vs. Conditional("DEBUG")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788605/if-debug-vs-conditionaldebug)

Comment: what about this code : #if DEBUG
            releaseMode = false;
#else
            releaseMode = true;
#endif

Comment: As you want. Choose the method that works best for you, which is the most appropriate for you and for the context. Choose what you find clearest, cleanest, most efficient, and most maintainable. Personally after reading and testing several things I chose the suggested code I found the most tidy.