# Skip execution of a line in Visual Studio without commenting it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio(2019) while debugging I want to skip multiple lines of codes across multiple projects (C#). Is there a way to do that?

I don't want to stop the execution at the break point of that line and then manually skip by "Set to next statement" every time.

*Reason: There's a logging feature that is not setup on my local machine and I don't have admin access to do so as well.

Comment: Or you can drag the yellow arrow next to the line numbers.

Comment: Can you mock/override the logging feature with a noop class by using an extra add via dependency injection?

Comment: Or even simplistically in the logging method have `#if DEBUG return` ?

Comment: Why do you was "without commenting it"? Do you not want to modify the logging code at all?

Comment: @Him they _don't_ want to manually skip each time the code encounters the log statements.

Comment: I would argue the duplicated link, probably better duplicate would be [C# if/then directives for debug vs release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104099/c-sharp-if-then-directives-for-debug-vs-release) if you could add it to the dupe info. @HimBromBeere

Comment: gunr2171 : Wanted to get rid of the manual task
Silvermind : I am not aware of the no-op class, 'll definitely take a look at it.
CaiusJard : Thanks 
CodeCaster : I was just curious if VS had that kind of feature, since there's a conditional debugging feature to pause on the debug point if any the condition we specified is true.
Cleptus : I agree with you, the duplicate link is not same as what my question was.

Comment: yea sorry for posting the whrong dupe. Thanks for pointing to the correct one @Cleptus

Answer (score 1):

this would do the work

```
 #if !DEBUG
        // Your code here
 #endif
```

Comment: Thanks @MorenajeRD, I'll use this feature

Answer (score 1):

> There's a logging feature that is not setup on my local machine and I don't have admin access to do so as well.

Either:

- Comment the ultimate call or method body out, or insert a `return;` at the first line, and don't commit it
- Create and inject a no-op logger
- If it's only for debugging, surround with `if (!Debugger.IsAttached) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster , I'll check what no-op logger means, but for the time being Debugger.IsAttached is a better idea for me.