# How to output solution configuration value to console window

Tags: c#

Given: Visual Studio 2022

How do I output solution configuration value (Debug, Release, etc) to console window using Console.WriteLine?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# if/then directives for debug vs release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104099/c-sharp-if-then-directives-for-debug-vs-release)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    #if DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine("Current Configuration: Debug");
    #elif RELEASE
        Console.WriteLine("Current Configuration: Release");
    //add more configurations if you have custom configurations.
    #else
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown Configuration");
    #endif
}
```

Use the `#if` and `#endif` **preprocessor directives** to check for the `defined symbols` and output the corresponding configuration name.