# MAUI-IOS is being uploaded to the wrong app in TestFlight

Tags: azure-devops, testflight, maui-ios

**Context**

We are using Azure DevOps to build and deploy a MAUI-IOS application to Testflight at the moment utilizing a few pipelines that is working perfectly. However I need to introduce additional apps to support a multi-environment setup (DEV,UAT,PRD). This requires separate app builds that point to separate API's depending on environment.
So we have the following apps:

- com.acme-dev.app
- com.acme-uat.app
- com.acme.app (prd)

**Problem**

I setup a new App in AppStore and I updated all the variables I could find in the source code but for some reason when publishing, the app is still published to the original app in TestFlight.

I updated the ApplicationId and ApplicationIdGuid properties in the .csproj for the build step.
Verified that parameters are correct in the resulting .ipa's Info.plist:

- CFBundleIdentifier set to the new App
- CFBundleDisplayName set to the new App

Then when executing the DevOps task (Apple App Store Release task) to publish the ipa to TestFlight, I can see that the fastlane command is utilizing the correct details:
`[command]/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/fastlane pilot upload --api_key_path /Users/runner/work/_temp/api_key.json -i /Users/runner/work/r1/a/deploy/AcmeApp.ipa -a com.acme-uat.app -p 3449341595`
Where -a is the BundleId from AppStore and -p is the AppleId.

I am sure I am missing a setting somewhere but for the life of me can't find it.
And I am baffled why fastlane would upload to the incorrect app even though it has a set of parameters pointing it to the correct one?

(I also created a new Provisioning Profile pointing to the new BundleId during upload)

Any help of ideas would be appreciated.

Tried updating all relevant ios parameters I could find.

Comment: Found a workaround.
Created a new App Store Connect API Key, so each environment is using it's own key now.
The API Key is not linked to a specific App, so no idea why this worked. All I can think is there is some sort of caching going on?


Leaving this question open if someone has a better explanation perhaps?

Comment: How you planned this? Do you have separate apps for each deployment (dev, prod)?

Comment: At first I only had one app and one build, then during the Release step I would:
- unpack IPA
- update API url (and other env variables) in info.plist
- repack IPA
- resign
- publish to testflight

This worked really great, but the problem is we could only test one version at a time on Testflight.

So ended up creating a new app for each environment:
com.acme.app
com.acme-dev.app
com.acme-uat.app

This way we can have all 3 installed via testflight for various users (with different access)
(Tried changing bundleid on the fly then later new builds but still didn't work)

Comment: My initial idea was to only have one app. Then during release it would publish UAT version to testflight, and PRD version to Business Manager.
DEV, either just an adhoc ipa or another platform like AppCenter.
But Testflight is great and would be nice to have all 3 versions side by side so opted now for 3 different apps.
I didn't find many posts out there regarding multiple environments for mobile builds, if anyone has a better idea it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The plan that you are following will cause severe backend handling and one day will break and you will not know what is the issue. It's not a good idea to have 1 app of each environment as the testing is not in the actual environment. As you can have multiple testflight versions uploaded, you can have different testing groups for each version for the same app, so each team/group will have access to the correct version from testflight.

Comment: Extra caution must be handled to do not submit a testing version to the app store. For that you can have different version numbers and build ids to understand what is uploaded to the testflight.

Comment: All the above are for both play store and app store. For play store is even more clear, as you can have internal testing, closed testing.

Comment: I come from a web development background, where we "build once, deploy many" so please excuse my ignorance.
We have an API (and Web App) for each environment.
How would you then setup the mobile app, keeping in mind that we want to test against the DEV and UAT API endpoints respectively?
(So we would first test on DEV, then progress to UAT when ready, and allow a wider group to test, then ultimately deploy to PRD where no testing is allowed)

My plan to make sure we never publish the test app is to automate everything in DevOps. So no manual deploys.

Comment: You will have many configuration settings to VS project. For example if debug then the endpoints will be different than the release. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104099/c-sharp-if-then-directives-for-debug-vs-release

Comment: Also note, that you have to test also the production version with some fake credentials depending on your app. Do not bet that your app will work even if all tests are passed. Also unit testing is a must for that size of teams.