# C# precompile directive - use a variable to tell which code to compile

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I use a web service in a C# project.
I test the project both online and on localhost.
I have code like:

```
 //var proxy = new PanoNestWebsite.ScheduleImagePanonest.ScheduleImageProcessingClient();
 //var s = new ScheduleImagePanonest.ScheduleImageProcessing();
 var proxy = new ScheduleImageLocal.ScheduleImageProcessingClient();
 var s = new ScheduleImageLocal.ScheduleImageProcessing();
```

For example, If I want to deploy it online I uncomment the first two lines, and comment the last two.

But I have much more changes to make, and I don't like commenting and uncommenting all lines.
How can I use proprocessing directives to define a variable like: IsLocal and I just set it to true to include the local code, or to false to include the server code?
How can I write something like this?

Comment: You can use the [`#if` preprocessor directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975355/ifdef-in-c-sharp); wrap your code in the appropriate block.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the kind of thing that you're dealing with, I'd recommend an alternative approach, possibly some IOC/DI where both of these classes implement an interface, and you configure in your app.config/web.config which type to point to it.

So instead of

```
var proxy = new ScheduleImageLocal.ScheduleImageProcessingClient();
```

you'd instead do

```
var proxy = IoCFactory.Resolve<IScheduleImagingProcessingClient>();
```

or something to that effect, however your library works.

If you use Unity, you would point the `IScheduleImagingProcessingClient` interface to a concrete type in your config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the project properties to define values or #define SOME_KEY then:

```
#if KEY

    ... Code goes here

#endif
```